# Ассоциация Vs Агрегация в чем разница?

Tags: ооп, uml

Тема заезженная но так как я начал изучать UML для меня это стало одним из вопросов на который я не могу найти четкого ответа...

Пишут что взаимосвязи между ассоциацией, агрегацией и композицией выражены следующим образом:

***ассоциация - это связь между классами, а агрегация это вложенность одного класса в другой, но при этом класс обертка не управляет сроком жизни вложенного объекта (который представлен ссылкой на искомый объект).***

**Композиция**
С ней все понятно и понятна ее разница от агрегации. Вложенные объекты должны создаваться в момент создания объекта контейнера и должны уничтожаться при уничтожении объекта контейнера. В противопоставление ей - идет агрегация, когда объект передается по конструктору, но все еще живет собственной жизнью.

**Начнем с ассоциации:**
В [данном примере](https://ravesli.com/urok-149-assotsiatsiya/#toc-0) в сети изображена множественная ассоциация как массив докторов у класса пациентов и напротив массив пациентов у класса докторов.

***Мне не понятно чем это отличается от агрегации, разве что только вложенные объекты не передавались через конструктор, но ведь поведение идентично.***

Мы так же имеем объект обертку и объект контейнер. Контейнер для докторов - класс пациенты и наоборот. Не один из контейнеров не управляет сроком жизни объектов которые хранит, иначе это уже было бы похоже на композицию.

Так же не понятна разница между ассоциацией и зависимостью. Ведь класс контейнер (рассуждения далее не касается приведенного примера) в любом случае скорее всего будет использовать объект ссылку на который хранит, получается что он зависимый объект, а тот что хранится в нем - независимый и из определения связи зависимости - *"Между элементами существует зависимость когда изменения в определении независимого элемента могут вызвать изменения в зависимом"*, соответственно из приведенного определения следует что ассоциация (как и агрегация да и композиция) всегда несет связь зависимости верно ?

**Агрегация** 
Классический пример агрегации всегда выглядит как передача вложенного объекта в объект контейнер. Может ли передача вложенного объекта по ссылке именно в момент создания объекта контейнера считаться основополагающим отличием между ассоциацией и агрегацией ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вроде тут все написано:

**Композиция** — это отношения части-целого. Часть в композиции может быть частью только одного объекта за раз. Например: cердце, которое является частью тела одного человека, не может быть частью тела ещё одного человека одновременно.

**Агрегация** в отличие от композиции, *части могут принадлежать более чем одному целому за раз*, и *целое не управляет существованием и временем жизни частей*. Например, отношения между человеком и его домашним адресом. У каждого человека есть свой адрес. Однако этот адрес может принадлежать более чем одному человеку за раз: например, вам и вашему соседу по комнате или родственникам, которые живут вместе с вами. Однако этот адрес не управляется человеком — адрес существовал до того, как человек заселился и будет существовать после того, как человек выселится. Кроме того, человек знает, по какому адресу он живет, но адрес, в свою очередь, не знает, что это за человек и вообще, сколько их там находится.

**Ассоциация** в отличие от композиции или агрегации, где часть является частью целого, объекты между собой никак не связаны. Подобно агрегации, первый объект может принадлежать сразу нескольким объектам одновременно и не управляется ими. Однако, в отличие от агрегации, где отношения однонаправленные, в ассоциации отношения могут быть как однонаправленными, так и двунаправленными (когда оба объекта знают о существовании друг друга).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://ravesli.com/urok-149-assotsiatsiya/#toc-0

Comment: Получается что все различие между ассоциацией и агрегацией состоит лишь в том, что ассоциация предполагает возможность двунаправленных связей (доктор знает по пациенте, а тот в свою очередь знает о докторе), а агрегация - предполагает лишь однонаправленную связь. Получается что агрегация - это частный случай ассоциации - верно ?

Comment: На счет однонаправленной и двунаправленной связей, да все верно. По поводу частного случая я бы не стал так говорить. У меня больше складывается параллель с видами связей  OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToMany

Comment: Соответственно связь OneToOne - относим к агрегации, а остальное к ассоциациям верно ? Однако же по всем признакам OneToOne тоже можно к ассоциации отнести, соответственно похоже на то что агрегация - это ее частный случай, однако данного вывода я не встречал не где...

Comment: Добавил сравнительную таблицу в ответ

Comment: То есть различие по большей мере характеризуется смыслом, а не признаками верно ли я понял ? К примеру венчики для взбивания миксером и миксер = агрегация, а револьвер и патрон = ассоциация верно ?

Comment: Благодарю за уделенное время. Последнее дополнение - если я совсем не в ту сторону думаю то дайте 2 примера на С++ (предпочтительно) или же C# схожих по содержанию но один для ассоциации другой для агрегации - тогда уже точно все должно стать ясным. Если же мой прошлый комментарий верен, то тогда просто благодарю за уделенное время.

Comment: В общем все верно, только пример `револьвер и патрон` мне в качестве ассоциации не нравится, я бы привел `человек и компания`.

Comment: @JamesBondCaesar
Гради Буч писал: В то время как связи обозначают равноправные или клиент серверные отношения между объектами, агрегация описывает иерархию целое/часть и позволяет переходить от целого к его компонентам. В этом смысле агрегации **является частным случаем** ассоциации.